# mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent, mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent and mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, shuffle

I just want to verify my understanding about these parameters and their  relationship, if I am wrong then please notify me.

- `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent` tells total amount of memory allocated to entire shuffle phase of a `reducer`.
- `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent` tell maximum percentage of the in-memory limit that a single shuffle can consume from `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent`.
- `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent` is the  usage threshold at which an in-memory merge will be initiated, expressed as a percentage of the total memory( `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent`) allocated for storing in-memory map outputs.
- But `Hadoop-2.6`  has a restriction that `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent` should be greater than `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent`. It means a single shuffle has all the keys of same type otherwise what is the purpose of this restriction and what is the relation between all three ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share my understanding on these properties, hope it would help. Advise me if anything is wrong.

`mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent` tells about the percentage of the reducer's heap memory to be allocated for the circular buffer to store the intermediate outputs copied from multiple mappers.

`mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent` tells about the maximum percentage of the above memory buffer that a single shuffle (output copied from single Map task) should take. The shuffle's size above this size will not be copied to the memory buffer, instead they will be directly written to the disk of the reducer.

`mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent` tells about the threshold percentage by where the in-memory merger thread will run to merge the available shuffle contents on the memory buffer into a single file and immediately spills the merged file into the disk.

It is obvious that in-memory merger thread should require at least 2 shuffle files to be present in memory buffer to initiate merge. So at any time the `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent` should be higher than any single shuffle file in memory controlled by `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent` property, by which it mandates that there should be at least more than one shuffle file to be present in the buffer for the merge process.

Comment: @Priyank, is the answer helpful to you get clarification?, if not let me know.

Comment: @ hserus, your answer is helpful but i do not know how to verify it.

Comment: @priyank, if you set the `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent` value below than `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent`, then you will get the exception on reducer phase. The explanation of the scenario is given in the answer..let me know what else clarification u need?